# Inheritance inconsistency with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, mongoid

mongoid version: mongoid (2.4.12)
rails -v #=>Rails 3.1.10

```
class A
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :foo
  def self.inherited(klass)
  end
end
class B < A
  field :bar
end
class C < A
end

#C.new
# => #<C _id: 514c9505e3e50a856b000001, _type: "C", foo: nil, bar: nil>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `super`, otherwise you will overwrite any previously defined `inherited` methods.  So your function should be:

```
def self.inherited(klass)
  super
  #your code here
end
```

You were clobbering the [mongoid inherited method](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/traversable.rb#L162).